# Deactivating avaudiosession after going back from videoviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation, avaudiosession, audiosession

I am trying to play video in background everything works just fine and the video play and get pause normally in background.But the only problem is whenever I go back from the from my 
videoviewcontroller(the view on which is played to menu), the video still remains in the background and you can see it as Musicplayer position. How can this be removed once I get out of videoviewcontroller

I have tried

```
    NSError *error;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:&error];

    NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", error);
```

output
ERROR: (null)
this code removes the video from the background

```
 [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:nil error:nil];
```

but if now if want to play the video again it will not play in background mode

Comment: Add code below and update your question with log.
`NSError *error;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO  error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@", error);`

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the reason. I hoped that error would not be nil.

Comment: @SviatoslavYakymiv : If i'm logged error, "NULL" error recived in simulator but when run in real device I got this error `Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=560030580 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 560030580.)`

Answer (score 0):

From Apple's:[AVAudioSession class documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setActive%3aerror%3a)

It says

> Deactivating your session will fail if any associated audio objects (such as queues, converters, players or recorders) are currently running.

So you need to stop any/all of this audio objects before calling the setActive:No

I had had similar issues while trying to perform this before stopping my audio queue.
In mi case I was using an external audio library (Dirac) and I just needed to call an AudioQueueStop method from this library before.

Comment: stopped the movie player before writing this code still no success :(